# Buggy HTML tables in IE7, help?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .tl, .tr, .bl, .br, .b, .t {
                background: #f00;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
            }

            .m {
                background: url('https://www.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo_lg.gif') #0f0;
            }

            table {
                width: 512px;
                height: 512px;
                border-spacing: 0px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="tl">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="t">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="tr">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="m">test</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bl">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="b">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="br">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine as long as I don't look at it with IE7. IE7 for some reason does not respect my width and height set to 16px and instead makes all rows and columns to take the average size. Oddly, this works in the Quirks mode though, but now in the standards mode, what's up?

P.S. Is there any other way of accomplishing a similar layout that has 16x16 corners, 16px top and bottom while the middle fits in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `height:100%;` for `.m`

Comment: modify the height value to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Try giving each cell some content:

```
<td class="tl">&nbsp;</td>
```

that should fix it.

Comment: That did not help. Nothing is different. :/

Comment: @rFactor on second look, this can't work because the total width of the table is more than 3 x 16 pixels, can it`?

Answer (score 1):

`border-spacing` and `border-collapse` are not supported in IE7 and below. Try using

`<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

***Update:***

I don't have IE7 nor IE6 here, so this is just a guess: try setting the width and height of .m to auto. If that doesn't work (since that would be too easy, right? :)), you can set the dimensions manually to 480px (512 - 2 * 16)

Comment: That `auto` setting did not work either. So, I guess my only chance to get it working in IE 7 is to calculate the height on my own?

Comment: @rFactor You can try those ie7.js scripts that solve issues in IE7 and other versions of IE...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <style>
          table  {
            width: 512px;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
        table .m 
        {
            background: url('https://www.google.com/images/logos/ssl_logo_lg.gif') #0f0;
             height: 512px; 
        }
        .tl, .tr, .bl, .br, .b, .t {
            background: #f00;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;

        }


    </style>
```

Comment: Did this not work then ? It seemed ok when I tested it in IE7 here at least.